# What is meant by Can't Interpolate {{getWebsite(thisProject[0].Site_ID}}?

Tags: angularjs

In the $scope, I have an object called **thisProject** which is logged as such in the console:

```
[    0: {
       [functions]: ,
       __metadata: { },
       AttachmentFiles: { },
       Attachments: false,
       AuthorId: 9,
       CloseDate: null,
       ContentType: { },
       ContentTypeId: "0x010087886FAC81322548A66F903FF786897C",
       Created: "2014-05-06T21:24:35Z",
       Division: "Information Technology",
       Division_ID: "21",
       Due_Date: "2014-05-12T07:00:00Z",
       EditorId: 9,
       FieldValuesAsHtml: { },
       FieldValuesAsText: { },
       FieldValuesForEdit: { },
       File: { },
       FileSystemObjectType: 0,
       FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject: { },
       Folder: { },
       GUID: "291f7307-b134-47e6-b13e-09fd86fe31ce",
       ID: 6,
       Id: 6,
       Imported_From_Project: false,
       Modified: "2014-05-06T21:24:35Z",
       OData__UIVersionString: "1.0",
       ParentList: { },
       Project_Lead: "Eyre, Jane",
       Priority: "High: Time Sensitive",
       Priority_Group: "High",
       Priority_ID: "3",
       Project_GUID: "1069",
       Requestor: "Plath, Sylvia",
       RoleAssignments: { },
       **Site_ID: "8",**
       Status: "In Progress",
       Status_ID: "2",
       Title: "Design Website Graphics",
       Website: "SharePoint"    },
    length: 1 ]
```

I also have an object in the $scope called **websites** which currently has 13 nodes where the pertinent one logs as this:

```
{
   [functions]: ,
   __metadata: { },
   ID: 8,
   Id: 8,
   Title: "SharePoint"
}
```

So I want to display the **name** (which in SharePoint that is called **Title**) of the website rather than the ID, so I added this function to the controller:

```
$scope.getWebsite = function(id){
    for(w=0; w<$scope.websites.length; w++){
        if($scope.website[w].ID == id){
        return $scope.website[w].Title;
        } // end if
    } // end for
};
```

Being quite new to AgularJS, that made perfect sense to me that I would find the match and assign the name of the site to $scope.getWebsite meaning that it would appear correctly when I put this in the template:

```
<p>{{getWebsite(thisProject[0].Site_ID)}}</p>
```

The console is filled with 13 error messages (one for each website) of

> Can't Interpolate `{{getWebsite(thisProject[0].Site_ID}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a couple of typos inside of `getWebsite`. In ...

```
if($scope.website[w].ID == id){
return $scope.website[w].Title;
```

the `website` property should be plural.

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KAvhfSWJBX6yCmtAMlqt?p=preview)

Comment: Marc, that was the issue ... it works fine now and I will mark this as the answer but I didn't want to close the question before asking one more question. Is there a way to make $scope.getWebsite dynamic (like $scope.getValue(list,id) and inside getWebsite change wherever websites property is hardcoded, substitute it with the passed in list parameter??? I have over 30 "lookups" and would rather be DRY if I can. Would it be if($scope. + list + [w].ID == id){ return $scope. + list + [w].Title; THAT WOULD BE SO BENEFICIAL.

Comment: Never mind. I'll make a separate question. Thanks again!